# Functions in Verilog for combinational logic

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I encountered something weird in a Verilog code, and I have doubts about it.

Someone used a `function` in Verilog in the following way:

```
Pipe #(.W($bits(Data))) MetaO (Clock, MyFunc(DataIn, I0, I1), DataOut);
function [DATA_SIZE-1:0] MyFunc (input [DATA_SIZE-1:0] DataIn, input I0, input I1);
  MyFunc    = DataIn;
  MyFunc[1] = X;
  if(I0) begin
    MyFunc[2]  = Y;
    MyFunc[3]  = K;
    MyFunc[4]  = I1;
end endfunction
```

So, what he tried to do here is to pipe `DataIn` to `DataOut`,
but to manipulate `DataIn` bits before the pipe, so he used `function` as the input to the `Input` port of the pipe.

My doubts are in the function itself.
He first of all kind of initialized `MyFunc` with `DataIn`,
and then in the following lines, assigns different values in the other bits depending on some stuff.

Because it's eventually combinatorial logic, I ask myself if it's a correct way to write Verilog.

Doesn't it create a race condition on some of these bits?
Can it make timing issues eventually?

What is another better way to write the same combinatorial logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't it create a race condition on some of these bits?

No, there is no race condition between the bits.  As you mentioned, the `function` is used to model combinational logic.  It correctly uses blocking assignments (`=`).

> Can it make timing issues eventually?

No, there are no timing issues.  The function explicitly sets 4 bits of `MyFunc`: 1-4.  But, all bits of `MyFunc` are set by the initialization line, no matter how big `DATA_SIZE` is:

```
MyFunc    = DataIn;
```

Since there are assignments to all bits, this avoids inferring unintended latches.

> What is another better way to write the same combinatorial logic?

Another way (not necessarily better) is:

```
always_comb begin
    MyFunc    = DataIn;
    MyFunc[1] = X;
    if (I0) begin
        MyFunc[2] = Y;
        MyFunc[3] = K;
        MyFunc[4] = I1;
    end
end
```

You would replace `MyFunc` with another signal name.

One advantage of the `function` is that it can be called many times in the code without duplicating the 9 lines of code above and with a different set of input signals.

Comment: so, the synthesizer in Verilog reads always_comb and function line by line from the first line and on? I imagined that all the lines inside the always_comb and function implemented in parallel.

Comment: @MichaelRahav: The assignments all occur during the same time step in simulation, but they occur in the order that you wrote in the code since you use the blocking assignment operator (`=`).

Comment: OK good to know, thanks!